# Not able to use SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

Whenever I am trying to create any SSIS Project I am getting following error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio is unable to load this document: To design
>   Integration Services packages in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). SSDT
>   has to be installed by one of these editions of SQL Server 2012:
>   Standard. Enterprise. Developer, or Evaluation. To install SSDT, run
>   SQL Server Setup and select SQL Server Data Tools.

[image]
Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using, the `Shell (Integrated)` version maybe? You can check this at `Help` > `About Microsoft Visual Studio` or on the loading screen when starting up.

Comment: Visual studio 2010 data tools. On same machine data tools for 2012 working.